# copy data from table to same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want Copy data from table to same table and ignore id and change value for 1 column (profile_name)

```
INSERT INTO profiles 
SELECT * FROM profiles where id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into table select col1,col2,col3,'custom value',(select x from y where z=1) from table where id=1
```

just ignore identity column name and think that you are inserting some values from another table

Comment: sorry but i cant understand this query

Comment: can u write this query with my examlpe ?

Comment: i can`t type all my columns becouse i have more than 50 column

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into yourtable (id, col1, col2, col3, profile_name)
(select null col1, col2, col3, New_value
  from table )
```

I understood that you want to copy a existing row , update profile_name column to some new value and id to null

If you have many columns,

```
SET @insertsql = CONCAT('insert into yourtable SELECT ', 
                       (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), 'id,', 'null,') , 'profile_name,', '''newvalue'',')
                          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                         WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'yourtable' 
                           AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourschema'), 
                       ' FROM yourtable');



prepare stmt from @insertsql   
EXECUTE @stmt;
```

Comment: thx for reply now i need use * without id and profile_name becouse i have 50 columns or more and i cant write him

Comment: @Mido Bona I have edited. Check

Comment: @Mido Bona I have edited. Check